# Problems with retraining a torch vgg16 network in Python

Tags: python, deep-learning, torch

I'm trying for ages to retrain the preimplemented vgg16 of torch in Python. The input data are spectrograms of .wav files, recorded from the sucktion sound of a flour + water mixture. The model should predict, whether the combination is 0%, 10%, 20%, 30%, 40%, 50%, 60% or 80% flour. I tried building a wrapper class to retrain the vgg16 but ran into an issue. The validations loss doesn't fall constantly. Here is the Code

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.models as models
import torch
import torchmetrics
from torch.cuda.amp import autocast

class Spektrogram_Classifier(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Spektrogram_Classifier, self).__init__()
        self.vgg16 = models.vgg16(pretrained=True)
        self.vgg16.features[16] = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=1)
        self.vgg16.features[23] = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        num_features = self.vgg16.classifier[6].in_features
        self.vgg16.classifier[6] = nn.Linear(num_features, 1)

    def forward(self, input):
        return self.vgg16(input)

    def training_step(self, batch):
        spectrograms, labels = batch
        spectrograms = spectrograms.repeat(1, 3, 1, 1)
        spectrograms = spectrograms.cuda()
        labels = labels.cuda()
        #with autocast():
        predictions = self.vgg16(spectrograms)
        predictions = predictions.cuda()
        loss = nn.functional.mse_loss(predictions, labels)
        return loss

    def validation_step(self, batch):
        spectrograms, labels = batch
        spectrograms = spectrograms.repeat(1, 3, 1, 1)
        spectrograms = spectrograms.cuda();
        predictions = self.vgg16(spectrograms).cuda()
        labels = labels.cuda();
        #print(pred)
        predictions = self.round_predictions_to_tens(predictions)
        predictions = predictions.cuda();
        #print(predictions)
        #loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        #loss = loss_fn(predictions, labels)
        loss = nn.functional.mse_loss(predictions, labels)
        #acc = mean_squared_error(labels, predictions)
        #acc = accuracy(predictions, labels, num_labels=8, num_classes=8, task="multiclass");
        KekWlolAMOGUS = torchmetrics.Accuracy(task="multiclass", num_classes=8).cuda();
        acc = KekWlolAMOGUS(predictions, labels)
        return {'val_loss': loss.detach(), 'val_acc' : acc}

    def round_predictions_to_tens(this, predictions):
        predictions = predictions.round().int();
        pred = []
        x = 0
        for t in predictions:
            for value in t:
                if value >= 65 and value < 75:
                    if abs(value - 65) >= abs(value - 75):
                        x = 80
                    else:
                        x = 60
                else:
                    if value % 10 > 4:
                        x = value + (10 - (value % 10))
                    else:
                        x = value - (value % 10)
                    if x >= 90:
                        x = 80
                    elif (x < 0):
                        x = 0
                pred.append([int(x)])
        return torch.tensor(pred)

    def validation_epochen_ende(self, results):
        losses_batch = [x['val_loss'] for x in results]
        epochen_loss = torch.stack(losses_batch).mean()
        accuracy_batch = [x['val_acc'] for x in results]
        epochen_acc = torch.stack(accuracy_batch).mean()
        return {'val_loss': epochen_loss.item(), 'val_acc': epochen_acc.item()}

    def epochen_ende(self, epoche, ergebnis):
        print("Epoch ", epoche, ", train_loss: ", ergebnis['train_loss'], ", val_loss: ", ergebnis['val_loss'], ", val_acc:", ergebnis['val_acc'])
```

If you have any idea or want to see further code i used to load the data pls contact me, any help is highly appreciated.